# Creating a separate doc from comments in a Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I'm working on a document with multiple sections which is bound to have loads of comments from various people. I would like to dynamically aggregate all comments on a particular section below that section.

If this is not possible, then at least a separate doc of all aggregated comments would be useful.

Is this possible in any manner?

Comment: Unfortunately is not possible to export comments to a single file which would made it easy to have them all in a new Document.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Google Drive/Google Apps for Work offer any programming interface to the comments, and I doubt there will be one. Comments in Google Docs are different from comments in MS Word in that each comment is actually a discussion thread where different contributors can go back and forth on a single subject, close the thread as resolved, or reopen the thread. It would be messy trying to organize the comments independently and without context.

A work-around would be turning on notification. You'd get periodic update mail on editing suggestion and comments. Then you can write Google Apps Script that parse the message content and try to come up with a summary.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments

Comment: Good find. I wonder if there is a way to create a document-wide comment using the API. Would be useful as a checklist of what's to be written.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to "extract" the comments:

- Export the google-doc as .docx
- Open the .docx
- Select all
- Copy
- Paste as an e-mail draft in Gmail. -> All the comments are gathered in the very end of the draft, every comment as a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you! Sometimes reviewers like to express their long-form opinions in a threaded conversation using only 200px-wide comment boxes. Unfortunately, this content is easily lost in a hidden menu and difficult to filter/search. My approach has been to use the API that Rubén mentioned and export them all to sheets that look like this:

[image]

If you are not interested in pursing a career in Apps Script (sarcasm), you can look for a comments exporter Add-On in the Workspace Marketplace that will do this automatically. But either way, it's very feasible to do what you are asking now.